# nuxt error, file not found from building project in server side render

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm having a problem with nuxt3, when I go to test it in development it's working normally, but if I try to build it with ssr: true, it causes me an error that is [19:35:28] ERROR [vite:vue] Could not load /home/darlan/\xC1Job/Projects produ\xE7\xE3o/newAuth/AuthVue/frontend/pages/recoverPassword.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=2f54abfe&lang.css?inline&used: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/darlan/\xC1rea de Trabalho/Projects produ\xE7\xE3o/newAuth/AuthVue/frontend/pages/recoverPassword.vue' [19:35:28] ERROR Nuxt Build Error: Could not load /home/darlan/\xC1rea de Trabalho/Projects produ\xE7\xE3o/newAuth/AuthVue/frontend/pages/recuperarSenha.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=2f54abfe&lang.css?inline&used: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/darlan/\xC1rea de Trabalho/Projetos produ\xE7\xE3o/newAuth/AuthVue/frontend/pages/recuperarSenha.vue'

I tried to reinstall the node update the dependencies, review the codes, rebuild the project, but nothing fixes the problem